# Rails 5 simple search form just won't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, search

- I have a navbar shared across all views by rendering it in application.html.erb with this form in it:

  ```
  <form class="form-inline d-none d-lg-inline-flex">    
    <%= form_tag search_query_path, method: :get do |f| %>
      <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query], class: "form-control", placeholder: "Search" %>
      <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>
    <% end %>
  </form>
  ```
- I want to search for similar titles in the Post model.
- The methods are in the PostsController as follows:

  ```
  def search_query
    @results = Post.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE title LIKE '%#{params[:query]}%'")
  end

  def search_query_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:query)
  end

  private :search_query_params
  ```

**The problem is:** the search keeps getting processed by the **current controller** of the current view. If I'm the the index page (in the PagesController), the query takes place there, just reloading the url like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=test+title
```

I've tried everything and can't find where my logic is wrong.

These are the routes:

```
get '/search_query', to: 'posts#search_query', as: 'search_query'
```

Comment: form_tag generates a form element, so you are nesting a form inside a form here. Try deleting the outer form.

Comment: Wow I didn't know that. It worked. Thanks man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`form_tag` generates a form element, so you are nesting a form inside a form here. Try deleting the outer form.